# Form cannot be submitted

Tags: 2010, infopath, error, form

I have two identical InfoPath forms on two different site collections within the same web application (SP2010). One works fine but the other produces this error when submitting the form....

> The form cannot be submitted. One or more field types are not
>   installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these
>   fields.
>
> An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server.  Log
>   ID:5567

I go to the list settings page but I have no idea which fields are not installed properly!

It opens in InfoPath and publishes without error.

I am a newbie to Sharepoint and the only references I can find when Googling talk about CAML queries and mismatching field names but I've no idea where to find CAML queries and fieldnames appear to be OK. I have played "spot the difference" with the working form and cannot find anything. All the fields are in a ContentType used by both forms.

The equivalent "edit" form works fine - again I can't see any significant difference with it.

Any clues would be most appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same exact issue. It's nutty.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).

Answer (score 1):

Go to list setting -> under columns -> delete invalid field.(i think it last column)
after delete field, modify infopath form and publish again

Comment: I don't see any option for "delete invalid field". Under "Columns" on the List Settings page I have a table listing the columns with headings of "Column (click to edit)", "Type" and "Used in". Under this table are 3 options - "Create Column", "Add from existing site columns" and "Indexed Columns".

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem. I deleted lookup fields and recreated that solved the problem for me. can you check by deleting lookup fields if u have any?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error.

One thing I have learned about SharePoint, InfoPath, and Nintex is that if you get an error, it is usually something very simple and small--it just requires a little energy to dig it up.

What the cause was in my case was I had created a field in my InfoPath form.  (I forgot to look to see if it actually showed up in my list settings in sharepoint--it should).
In any case, thankfully I remember creating it yesterday.  I found that field in InfoPath and deleted it.

The error means there is a field somewhere that isn't being filled out properly.

My field was a date and time field, the error explained that it needed to be in a date format--and also did list the field's name.